# Will the "new" chardev interface move all GPIO questions to "Off Topic"?

Tags: discussion

I just finished making a [comment to an OP explaining why his Question had been voted "Off Topic"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136496/83790). I was also thinking of my recent [Question regarding the "new" chardev GPIO API](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136479/confusion-with-libgpiod-and-the-gpiod-user-tools).

This caused me to wonder: `Will the "new" chardev interface move all GPIO questions to "Off Topic"?` By way of explanation, my thinking was that since the chardev API is part of the Linux kernel, and the device tree is part of the Linux kernel, and etc... Will GPIO questions perhaps move "across the line" into Off-Topic?

Some may wonder if there is another motive behind this question. I asked myself this question; and honestly - I can't say. I can say that the dividing line between "on-topic" and "off-topic" does seem to be very fuzzy to me at times. And so perhaps this question is just food for thought?

Answer (score 2):

If the GPIO library being used is specific to the Raspberry Pi I'd expect the question to be on topic.

It's unlikely that the `/dev/gpiochip` interface makes a dramatic difference to working with the Pi GPIO.  `/dev/gpiochip` will never meet the needs of those who need the highest performance.

Comment: Perhaps not, but I wonder if those in need of high performance are using RPi & Linux? On a related point, I do recall reading *"somewhere"* that the "PiGuys" at the foundation are pushing to have at least one aspect of the *odd* `chardev` interface changed; i.e. the absence of *persistence*.